# GoogleMaps InfoWindow not appearing when Marker is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps, for-loop, infowindow, marker

I have three arrays : myLats, (latitudes) myLngs (longitudes) and myLocs (address strings)
e.g. myLats[0] =  53.3534751, ,myLngs[0] = -2.5682085, myLocs[0] = Longwood Rd Appleton Warrington. So the elements of each array all correspond to each other numerically.

When constructing the map in my initialize() function, I loop through these to place multiple markers at the correct coordinates, and i'm also trying to have each marker having an infowindow appear when clicked, yet when i click a marker an infowindow simply does not appear. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.00366, -2.547855),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

    var marker, infowindow, i;

    for (i = 0; i <= myLats.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLats[i], myLngs[i]),
            map: map,
            clickable: true,
            icon: '". url::base() ."resources/icons/accident.png',
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: myLocs[i],
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a common problem when dealing with more than one marker.  You aren't in fact creating a new window for each marker but must redefining the single window for each marker.

You'll find the problem and solution on page 88 onwards of [Google Map API V3](http://books.google.ie/books?id=gHb8m0GSV2MC&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=Wrap%20the%20event%20listener%20inside%20an%20anonymous%20function&source=bl&ots=8OgTi2CLSC&sig=T5xnW0IZvRueLBT7N8m9XU35BLQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1hBiT4CRLIiJhQf_07yWCA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Wrap%20the%20event%20listener%20inside%20an%20anonymous%20function&f=false)

If you are new to Google Maps API, I would recommend reading that book, it gave me a great start and I avoided a lot of the "common" mistakes.

Hope this helps.
Jim

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes, like adding the markers inside a function, adding 'var', and changing i <= myLats.length to i < myLats.length. It was a combination of these changes that made it work.

```
    var  myLats = [ 54.20366, 54.42366, 54.64366];
    var  myLngs = [ -2.54788, -2.66788, -2.78788];
    var  myLocs = [ "Loc a" , "Loc b" , "Loc c"];

function initialize()
{
var myOptions =
{
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.00366,-2.547855),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);

var marker, infowindow, i;

for (i=0; i < myLats.length; i++)
{
  addMarker(i);
}
function addMarker(i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLats[i],myLngs[i]),
        map: map,
        clickable: true,
        //icon: '". url::base() ."resources/icons/accident.png',
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: myLocs[i]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
}
```

However, I'm guessing you want a solution that keeps only one infowindow open, I had this figured out first:

```
    var  myLats = [ 54.20366, 54.42366, 54.64366];
    var  myLngs = [ -2.54788, -2.66788, -2.78788];
    var  myLocs = [ "Loc a" , "Loc b" , "Loc c"];
    var  map, marker, infowindow, i;


function initialize()
{
var myOptions =
{
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.00366,-2.547855),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);


infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ });
for (i = 0; i < myLats.length; i++) {
  addMarker(i);
}
}

function addMarker(i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLats[i],myLngs[i]),
        map: map,
        clickable: true
        //icon: '". url::base() ."resources/icons/accident.png'      
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        infowindow.setContent(myLocs[i]);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```